# Modifying number based on % change

Tags: c#, economics

I'm trying to create a price based on the amount of supply available. For example, if we have a stock of 40 million in the commodity with a base price of $20, I need the price to decrease by 0.06% when every 0.125% change upwards in the supply, and to increase by 0.1% every 0.125% change downwards in the supply.

Here is what I have been able to come up with so far...

```
 public void AddDailyCrudeOil() {
      CrudeOilSupplyRussia += DailyCrudeOilAmountRussia;
      /* 
       * Every 0.125% increase in supply, has a 0.06% decrease in the price. 
       * Conversely, any 0.125% decrease in supply, has a 0.1% increase in price. 
       * At our base supply, 40M, 0.125% will be 50K, and the condition will be true as our daily supply delivery is 100k
       * */
      if (DailyCrudeOilAmountRussia > CrudeOilSupplyRussia * 0.00125f) {
          CrudeOilPriceRussia *= -0.0006f;
      }
  }
```

But of course, this will only work once and not incrementally.

I've been stuck on this for longer than I'd like to admit, and any guidance is very welcome.

Comment: Is this compound?  so from 40,000,000 to 40,050,000 is the first 0.125%, but the next 0.125% would then be 50,062.50?  or is it always 0.125% of the base 40,000,000?

Comment: It will be 0.125% of the base 40,000,000! Sorry I should have mentioned that. That is essentially how much additional supply the producer adds every day.

Comment: same for the price decrease? is that 0.06% worked out from the inital price then applied as a fixed amount? so if the price starts at 100, then it would go down to 99.94 for the first 0.125% supply increase, then 99.88 for the next 0.125% and so on (the second would still be 0.06% of 100, NOT 0.06% of 99.94?)

Comment: Yes sir that is correct.

**40,000,000 100.00**
40,050,000 99.94
**40,100,000 99.88**
40,150,000 99.82
**40,200,000 99.76**
40,250,000 99.70
**40,300,000 99.64**
40,350,000 99.58
**40,400,000 99.52**
40,450,000 99.46
**40,500,000 99.40**
Hope that makes it clearer! thanks for your time.

Comment: Added an answer which I think meets these requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  Written as an NUnit Test and using "Shouldly" for assertions, this passes.  Note I'm using Decimals to avoid any weird rounding problems.

```
[TestFixture]
public class tmp
{
    [Test]
    public void test()
    {
        var baseAmount = 40000000M;
        var basePrice = 100;
        var percentIncreaseTrigger = 0.00125M;
        var percentDecreaseInPrice = 0.0006M;

        GetNewPrice(baseAmount, basePrice, percentIncreaseTrigger,
                    percentDecreaseInPrice, 40050000)
            .ShouldBe(99.94M);

        GetNewPrice(baseAmount, basePrice, percentIncreaseTrigger, 
                    percentDecreaseInPrice, 40100000)
            .ShouldBe(99.88M);

        GetNewPrice(baseAmount, basePrice, percentIncreaseTrigger, 
                    percentDecreaseInPrice, 40400000)
            .ShouldBe(99.52M);

    }

    private decimal GetNewPrice(decimal baseAmount, decimal basePrice, 
           decimal trigger, decimal decreaseBy, decimal newAmount)
    {
        //work out what the trigger % is as an absolute amount
        var triggerAmount = baseAmount * trigger;

        //work out the price decrease as an absolute amount of the base price
        var priceDecreaseAmount = basePrice * decreaseBy;

        //work out how much over the baseAmount we are
        var amountOver = newAmount - baseAmount;

        //work out how many times we can fit the 0.125% into this - 
        //ignore fractional parts
        var numberOfTriggers = Math.Floor(amountOver / triggerAmount);

        //multiply the priceDecrease amount up by this
        var totalToTakeOffPrice = priceDecreaseAmount * numberOfTriggers;

        var result = basePrice - totalToTakeOffPrice;

        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Give me a minute to run this! Thank you in advance as it looks right to me!

Comment: Just going over this some more, will respond again soon! Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Just realised I'm not doing the flip side of increasing price as the quantity goes down... but just adding a check for the newAmount being higher/lower then altering the values as appropriate should be pretty trivial

Answer (score 0):

I would make a linear function that, for any supply, returns the correct price. That gives you a continous price function that doesn't have 'steps' for each 0.125% increase in supply. If you need the steps, then disregard this answer.

With your requirements you'd probably need to have 2 formulas. One for above 40 million supply and one for below since it looks like they have different slopes. But do you really want a 'kink' in your price curve at 40 million supply?

```
  static void Main()
  {
        var price = GetPrice(40050000.0);
        Console.WriteLine(price);
  }

  private static double GetPrice(double supply)
  {
            if (supply > 40000000.0)
            {
                 double slope = -0.012 / 50000.0; // Decrease price by 0.012 for each 50000 increase in supply
                 double origin = 20 - (slope * 40000000.0); // Calculate the price at 0 supply given the price at 40 million supply
                 return origin + supply * slope; // Price at the given supply
            }
            else
            {
                 double slope = -0.02 / 50000.0; // Decrease price by 0.02 for each 50000 increase in supply
                 double origin = 20 - (slope * 40000000.0); // Calculate the price at 0 supply given the price at 40 million supply
                 return origin + supply * slope; // Price at the given supply
            }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

In my Excel calculations, at 35m supply, price should be $22.10, but from Unity yours gets me $26? Thats 0.3% per 0.125% drop instead of 0.1%. 

How would I go about correcting that?

Comment: I've changed my answer to give $20 at 40 million. I've expanded it to have different slopes above and below 40 million. It give $22 at 35 million. I think that's correct. A 5 million drop is 100 drops of 50000 (0.125%). So that should give an increase of 100 times 0.1% or a 10% increase.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick

```
public double practicalCase(double actualStock, double baseStock, double percentChange, double basePrice,
        double priceDecrease, double priceIncrease)
    {
        double changeAmount = baseStock * percentChange;
        double priceChanges = Math.Floor(Math.Abs(baseStock - actualStock) / changeAmount);

        if (actualStock > baseStock)
            return (basePrice - (priceDecrease * priceChanges));
        else
            return (basePrice + (priceIncrease * priceChanges));
    }
```

tried it with the following cases

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestPracticalCase()
    {
        Assert.Equal(100d, _propertyManager.practicalCase(actualStock: 40000000d, baseStock: 40000000d, percentChange: 0.00125d,
            basePrice: 100d, priceDecrease: 0.06d, priceIncrease: 0.1d));

        Assert.Equal(99.94d, _propertyManager.practicalCase(actualStock: 40050000d, baseStock: 40000000d, percentChange: 0.00125d,
            basePrice: 100d, priceDecrease: 0.06d, priceIncrease: 0.1d));

        Assert.Equal(101d, _propertyManager.practicalCase(actualStock: 39500000d, baseStock: 40000000d, percentChange: 0.00125d,
            basePrice: 100d, priceDecrease: 0.06d, priceIncrease: 0.1d));
    }
```